# PostgreSQL field timestamp without timezone - how to check if it equals today

Tags: javascript, postgresql, date, datetime

I have a date field in a postgresql database as "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE".

It gets stored as: `2016-02-03 00:00:00` for an event that happens today (Wed 3rd Feb 2016). I want to return all events from today up until two weeks in the future.

I set a date two weeks from now:

```
var twoWeeksFromNow = new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
```

If I create today's date as so:

```
var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0);
```

I get a timestamp out of range error.

If I set it as

```
var today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0));
```

It just doesn't return today's events.

My query looks like:

```
"SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date >= today AND event_date < twoWeeksFromNow"
```

How do I get it to match today's date with a javascript date object or stringified date object? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: [*setHours*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.sethours) returns the time value of the modified Date object, not a Date object or string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be aware that "today" is defined by your current timezone setting. If all your operations are confined to the same time zone, it's fine to use `timestamp [without time zone]`. Else, consider `timestamp with time zone` - and define "today" more closely.

Next, you shouldn't call a `timestamp` column <strike>`event_date`</strike> because it's not a date. A *date* does not include a time component.

Defining "from today up until two weeks in the future" to be a period of exactly 14 days (so if it's Friday today, it ends on Thursday):

```
SELECT *
FROM   events
WHERE  event_date >= current_date  -- work with time zone session
AND    event_date <  current_date + 14;
```

- The timezone setting of your current session defines "today".
- Don't cast the column to date like another answer suggests <strike>`event_date::date`</strike> or the expression is not [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable) any more and you can't use a plain index on `(event_date)` - which is the key to performance in bigger tables.
- You can just add integer to a `date` (to add days). The same is not possible with timestamps. The date is converted to timestamp implicitly, assuming time `00:00` in the process.

If you want to make sure that "today" is not shifted to some other time zone:

```
SELECT *
FROM   events, date_trunc('day', now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna') AS t
WHERE  event_date >= t
AND    event_date <  t + interval '14 days';
```

This is guaranteed to return correct results independent of the current time zone setting.

Replace 'Europe/Vienna' with your time zone name. Use a time zone name (not a time zone abbreviation or a numeric offset) to defend against DST (daylight saving time) nonsense. You can find them all in the system table `pg_timezone_names`.

Detailed explanation:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a solution for your problem.

```
    SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date ::date >= CURRENT_DATE  AND event_date ::date < CURRENT_DATE +14
```

Comment: see the new solution @OliverJ90